# マクロで「一致する行の下に追加表示する行数」が記憶されません

Tags: emeditor

Version 21.7.911で、下記のマクロを使っています。

editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4445);
data = clipboardData.getData( "Text" );
document.Filter(data, 0, eeFindReplaceRegExp);

フィルターで「一致する行の下に追加表示する行数」を手動で1に設定しても、このマクロを実行すると「一致する行の下に追加表示する行数」が0になってしまいます。

最近バージョンアップするまでは、直前の設定が引き継がれていたと思います。
「一致する行の下に追加表示する行数」を記憶させる方法があればご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Filter` メソッドにパラメータが追加され、最後の2つのパラメータで、「一致する行の上に追加する行数」、「一致する行の下に追加する行数」が指定できるようになりました。次のように、行数を指定して呼び出してください。

```
nAbove = 0;
nBelow = 1;
document.Filter(data, 0, eeFindReplaceRegExp, 0, 0, 0, nAbove, nBelow);
```

Comment: おかげさまでうまく行きました。パラメータの追加でより便利になりました。